# VimWiki - How to create a link to a code file, and open that file with vim

Tags: neovim, plugin-vimwiki

I am new to VimWiki.

I am currently taking my class notes with VimWiki, and love the organization it provides.However I want to link my SQL & c code from class to one of my classes index's, but whenever I try to link it with

```
[[FileName.FileType]]
```

It just comes out as

```
[[FileName.FileType.wiki]]
```

I also tried

```
[[file:\FileName.FileType]]
```

and it did not work in the context of being unable to open with VIM, by HTML hyperlink path showed

```
file:::C\VimWiki_HTML\FileName.FileType
```

Is there a way I can make it link to the correct file type, and through vim be able to open that file

Comment: Well, I don’t know the answer, but I feel vindicated that my personal wiki code just uses `gf` and permits any kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

> but whenever I try to link it with `[[FileName.FileType]]`
> It just comes out as `[[FileName.FileType.wiki]]`

Vimwiki use the wiki syntax `[[name]]` to handle wiki files (with extension `.wiki`) in your wiki space (by default `~/vimwiki`, so this example will look for the file `~/vimwiki/name.wiki` that's all.)

Maybe there's a way to derogate that rule, I dunno (I never had that need.) But Vimwiki also supports markdown syntax, and that's what I use for external (and non-wiki) files: `[filename or description](path/to/FileName.FileExtension)`

> I also tried `[[file:\FileName.FileType]]`

Yes, you can also use wiki syntax for local resources/files with appropriate prefix. But still use forward slashes, even on Windows filesystem: `[[file:path/to/FileName.FileExtension]]` or `[[local:path/to/FileName.FileExtension]]` is perhaps what you were looking for.